# Appending to empty array in a for loop (python)

Tags: python, numpy

How do I append values in an empty numpy array? I have an array of values that I want to perform a mathematical equation on and from those values I want to append it to a new empty array. What I have is:

```
qa = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20])    

values_a = np.array([])
for n in qa:
    value = np.math.factorial(n + 19)/(np.math.factorial(n)*np.math.factorial(19))
    values_array = np.append(values_a, value)
```

However, it isn't appending and not sure why?

Comment: Check the variable names.

Comment: Using `np.append` in a loop is not a good idea.  List append, or even a list comprehension is faster and easier to use right.

Comment: `values_array = np.array(list(map(lambda n: np.math.factorial(n + 19)/(np.math.factorial(n)*np.math.factorial(19)), qa)))`

Comment: As @hpaulj said, array are usually not good for dynamic problem where you increase the size of array one after another. IF YOU HAVE TO use NumPy array, then define its size first and add its element using index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the array name, you're using `values_array` instead of `values_a`. Here's a code that works using your logic:

```
qa = np.arange(21)
values_a = np.array([])
for n in qa:
    value = np.math.factorial(n + 19)/(np.math.factorial(n)*np.math.factorial(19))
    values_a = np.append(values_a, value)
```

Nevertheless, as some comments say, it is not recommended to use `numpy.append` inside a loop, so you can use [`scipy.special.factorial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.factorial.html) instead. It allows calculating the factorial of the whole array element-wise:

```
from scipy.special import factorial
factorial(qa + 19)/(factorial(qa) * factorial(19))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the result of `np.append` to `values_array`, but next time through your loop you are overwriting that assignment.  Instead, you want to assign the results of `np.append` into `values_a` so that you are building up `values_a` each successive iteration:

```
values_a = np.array([])
for n in qa:
    value = np.math.factorial(n + 19)/(np.math.factorial(n)*np.math.factorial(19))
    values_a = np.append(values_a, value)
```